# Is a circular restriction possible (will elaborate)

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, circles

When making rational functions, you may get various kinds of restrictions (as the difference in power increase the difference is the shape of restriction) so if by stating an implicit function that can not be simplified can we make a rational implicit function with a circular restriction with a circle inside. (as far as i know implicit derivatives of circles can be graphed so I think it will be possible to apply it to this idea.) 
Sorry for any dumb logic related math mistakes in the question, I just finished highschool calc and was just curious about this the whole way through.

Comment: By restrictions do you mean points left out of the domain?

Comment: Please edit the question to make your point clear. What do you mean by restriction? What do you mean by a circular restriction?